# Repeated textButtons and child containers - Is there a way to make this code shorter?

Tags: function, flutter, dart

When pressed, each container plays a sound.

[image]

I already shortened it by making the function playSound. But is there a way to make this even shorter?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void playSound(int soundNumber) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 90,
                  color: Color(0xffFF80AB),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(2);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 90,
                  color: Color(0xff880E4F),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(...),
              TextButton(...),
              TextButton(...),
              TextButton(...),
              TextButton(...),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly, I'd like to mention that I used textButton because flatButton etc. are already obsolete. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class for your widget and pass index parameter to it for pick color and sound and use `ListView.builder` for creating each widget like code below:

```
class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: 7,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return CustomButtonWidget(
                index: index,
              );
            }),
      ),
    ));
  }
}


class CustomButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  CustomButtonWidget({this.index});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        playSound(index + 1);
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 90,
        color: index.isEven ? Color(0xffFF80AB) : Color(0xff880E4F),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of creating another stateless widget when you are only using the widget once in your `ListView.builder`. This just adds more boilerplate code.

Comment: Maybe you will want use it in another class or file  in project in future. when we have custom widget  we can use it everywhere  and we prevent  writing repetitive  code.

Comment: Correct, but in his question it is used once. By utilizing ListView.builder no code is repeated. You are just adding boilerplate code.

Comment: Why use stateful instead of stateless?

Comment: I created that class just for test your code and if you don't have state to update your screen you can use stateless too. I focused on CustomButtonWidget. for your question.

Answer (score 1):

As I see your TextButtons are so similar so you can create a Stateless object which returns a TextButton with similar properties and different color and onPressed method!

```
class MyTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final color;
  final onPressed;
  const MyTextButton({
    Key key,
    this.color,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        this.onPressed;
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 90,
        color: this.color,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use this `MyButton` instead of `TextButton` like this:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void playSound(int soundNumber) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MyTextButton(
                color: Color(0xffFF80AB),
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
              ),
              MyTextButton(
                color: Color(0xffFF80AB),
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
              ),
              MyTextButton(...),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does Key key mean?

Comment: A Key is an identifier for Widgets, Elements and SemanticsNodes.
A new widget will only be used to update an existing element if its key is the same as the key of the current widget associated with the element. It is not important you can delete it if you want. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html#:~:text=A%20Key%20is%20an%20identifier,widget%20associated%20with%20the%20element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it shorter by using the [`ListView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html). It looks like the following:

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 7,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            playSound(index + 1);
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 90,
            color: index % 2 == 0 ? Color(0xffFF80AB) : Color(0xff880E4F),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Essentially you are looping through 7 times in the `itemBuilder` and returning the `TextButton`. You are using the index to determine the color and the value passed to `playSound`.

You may need to wrap your ListView in an `Expanded` widget if you are getting an `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.` error.